# radio button loses value on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, radio-button

Hi I have a set of radio buttons for "yes" and "no" values which have a name="choice".  "yes" is checked by default. They're both runat="server".  I read the choice on postback like below.  It works perfectly fine as long as the validation doesn't fail.  For example, if I select "no" and validation fails on postback,  I still see "no" selected.  But if I submit the form after correcting everything, the value read is "yes" on server side!  Is this a bug in .net, and if so, how do i fix this?

```
foreach (string key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
{
    if (key.EndsWith("choice"))
        return Request.Form[key] == "yes";
}
```

Comment: Does the aspx page have "EnableViewState" enabled? I ran into a similar problem once, with a control showing one thing on the form but the data submitted was completely different. It was fixed when I set EnableViewState to true.

Comment: yes the view state is enabled.  That's how the form still retains the value that was selected before postback.  So if I selected "no" before postback, the re-rendered page still shows "no" selected.  However, if I submit after this, the value that is read back is "yes"

Comment: Understood. In my case, I had ViewState enabled on my control, but not the page, so it would keep track of updates on postback as well, but the page itself apparently didn't care, so results would become quite unusual at times. Sorry I can't help any further.

Comment: ok this is weird.  I added enableviewstate="true" just for the heck of it, and it worked!!  Then I removed it, and it still works now!  WTF!

Comment: Is it reproduced if, instead of merely removing EnableViewState, you issue EnableViewState="false"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was a problem with me disabling viewstate at a deeper level.

Answer (score 0):

If you are DataBinding the RadioButton or one of its ancestor Controls, make sure you check for PostBacks when setting the initial value:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
     YourControlId.DataBind();
```